# Polars Series.to_numpy() does not return ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-polars

I was trying to convert a series to a numpy array via `.to_numpy()` but unlike what the documentation shows i am not getting a ndarray out but a seriesview

Running exactly the example in the documentation:  https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.to_numpy.html

```
s = pl.Series("a", [1, 2, 3])
arr = s.to_numpy()
arr
type(arr)
```

I get

```
[1 2 3]
<class 'polars.series._numpy.SeriesView'>
```

Am i doing something wrong here and if not how should i work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is incorrect. `Series.to_numpy()` **does** return a `series._numpy.SeriesView` object, however by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/series/_numpy.py#LL13C13-L13C13), `series._numpy.SeriesView` inherits the `np.ndarray` class and just adds another attribute to the class for internal purposses.

So for all purposes, there's nothing you need to do. You can treat the return value of `Series.to_numpy()` as a `np.ndarray` because every `polars.series._numpy.SeriesView` is also a `np.ndarray`. Any method or attribute that an `np.ndarray` object has, it will also be present on a `polars.series._numpy.SeriesView` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the actual numpy array without making additional copies you can use the `.base` attribute.

```py
s = pl.Series("a", [1, 2, 3])
arr = s.to_numpy().base
type(arr)
>>> numpy.ndarray
```